# BindingSource and Entity Framework are not aware of each other

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, devexpress

In our project we are using

- Entity Framework
- Repository Pattern + Unit of Work Pattern together
- We are using DevExpress controls.

While at then beginning I was using a LIST now after the suggestion of Gosha (thanks gosha), i updated the code to BINDINGLIST
The related part of the  code for initializing our grid is :

```
// New repository instance by UOW (unit of work)
repXtraGridAddXtraEditor = new RepositoryObject.DesignLayer.XtraGridViewAddXtraEditorRep(UOW, true);
// new bindinglist and fill it    
blAddXtraGridEditor = new BindingList<BusinessObject.DesignLayer.XtraGridViewAddXtraGridEditor>(repXtraGridAddXtraEditor.Query(t => t.XtraGridViewId == XtraGridViewId).ToList());

// BindingSource bsource to be filled by blAddXtraGridEditor 
bSource = new BindingSource(); // { DataSource = XtraGridViewXtraGridEditorList};
bSource.DataSource = blAddXtraGridEditor;
// PASS İT TO GRID
grdXtraGridAddXtraEditor.DataSource = bSource;
```

Now

1. The grid >  grdXtraGridAddXtraEditor
2. BindingSource> bSource
3. BindingList> blAddXtraGridEditor

are AWARE OF EACH OTHER, which means when we delete a record from the grid, it is also deleted from Bindingsource and bindinglist

When we delete a row from our grid

```
// Delete from grid ( from screen)
gvwXtraGridAddXtraEditor.DeleteRow(gvwXtraGridAddXtraEditor.FocusedRowHandle);

//reflect changes to DB
UOW.Db.SaveChanges();  // WHICH MAKES NOTHING :)
```

Other codes which has no effect on the outcome of saving the changes to Db:

```
bSource.EndEdit();
blAddXtraGridEditor.ResetBindings();
bSource.ResetBindings(false);
UOW.Db.SaveChanges();
```

The delete is not reflected to EntityFramework(and or UOW)

In other words, the grid and Entity Framework are not aware of each other.

1. Is there something that I am missing ?
2. Is there a better alternative ?

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the ToList method to obtain records. The IList interface does not support notifications of its changes. You need IBindingList. Use the [DbExtensions.ToBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696575%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method to obtain it. This method is an extension method of the `ObservableCollection<T>` class. You should use it to return your datasource. I've found the [Building a simple Expense Tracker application using Grid Control for Windows Forms. Part 1. Creating a new Data Bound application.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18899) article on DevExpress that can be helpful here.

Comment: Hi @gosha, updated the question.  Could you check it again thanks

Comment: To be honest, not sure that `blAddXtraGridEditor = new BindingList<BusinessObject.DesignLayer.XtraGridViewAddXtraGridEditor>(repXtraGridAddXtraEditor.Query(t => t.XtraGridViewId == XtraGridViewId).ToList());` will work. Try `blAddXtraGridEditor = repXtraGridAddXtraEditor.Query(t => t.XtraGridViewId == XtraGridViewId).ToBindingList();`

Comment: BTW, try to replace a DevExpress Grid with a standard DataGridView. Will they work identically?

Comment: Hi Gosha, blAddXtraGridEditor = repXtraGridAddXtraEditor.Query(t => t.XtraGridViewId == XtraGridViewId).ToBindingList()  >>>> ToBindingList is not available ?

Comment: This method works with ObservableCollection<T>. EF usually returns them. Can you access ObservableCollection in your repository?

Comment: thanks gosha , ObservableCollection solved the issue